# Error: Port py27-pygoocanvas not found on MAC bigSur

Tags: python, ns-3, pyviz

I wanted to install NS-3 on my macOS, so I followed the documentation but in the end Python-visualizer did not get installed. So for that I tried installing it by following steps [here](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/PyViz).

`>>port install py27-pygtk py27-pygoocanvas py27-pygraphviz`

This took 10 minutes to execute and ended with a message as: `Error: Port py27-pygoocanvas not found`

I cannot find any help online regarding how to fix this, please guide.
Thank you.

Comment: What version of ns3 and python are you using?